# Getting error while deploying VRFCooridnatorV2Mock

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat, smart-contract-wallets, mock

this is deploy script for mock

```
const{getNamedAccounts, deployments, network, ethers}=require("hardhat");

const baseFee=ethers.utils.parseEther("0.25");
const gasFee= 1e9;

module.exports=async function({getNamedAccounts, deployments}){
    const {deploy, log}=deployments;
    const {deployer}=await getNamedAccounts();
    const chainId=network.config.chainId;

    if(chainId=31337/*developmentChains.includes(network.name)*/){
        console.log("Local network detected, Deploying Mocks !");

        await deploy("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock", {
            from: deployer,
            log: true,
            args: [baseFee, gasFee]
        })
    }
    log("Mocks Deployed");
    log("!-------------------------------------------------------------")

}
module.exports.tags=["all", "mocks"]
```

I am getting error of -  "Error: No Contract deployed with name VRFCoordinatorV2Mock"

please help

This is the repo link- https://github.com/DeadmanAbir/Hardhat-Raffle

Answer (score 0):

In your VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol contract you have:
pragma solidity >0.8.0; try pragma solidity ^0.8.0;